# What is the Pythonic way to open a list of files so that they will be closed?

Tags: python

If I want to open one file I can do

```
with open(filename, "w") as f:
  ...
```

For a fixed number of files:

```
with open(name1, "w") as f1, \
     open(name2, "w") as f2, \
     open(name3, "w") as f3:
  ...
```

But that would only work if I know the number of files when writing the code. What would be the correct way to open files if the names were in a list?

My first inclination was to make a list of the file objects as they were opened, then use try...finally, something like

```
try:
  files = []
  for name in namelist:
    files.append(open(name, "w"))

  ... do stuff with the files list ...

finally:
  for f in files:
    f.close()
```

If there is a problem opening one of the files, the script tidies up and quits without writing any of them, and that seems good to me.

Not sure what the best way is to handle errors when closing; a problem closing one file would prevent the ones after that from being closed, unless I trap everything; but that doesn't seem good because the error is lost.

Is there a neater/better/more elegant way? A way to extend `with` to a list maybe?

Comment: Why don't you use `with` inside the `for` loop?

Comment: How many of the files need to be open *simultaneously*? Why?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - because I am going to be looping over a data set and writing different report info to the files. Seems a waste to loop over the data set multiple times when I can loop over it once and write each record to the appropriate file.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych - if I was opening and closing them one at a time then I would be doing that. But I don't see how that could be coded if I want to open them all, then write to them, then close them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library offers a nice way of doing this using [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack).

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(fin, "w")) for fin in files]
    # All opened files will automatically be closed at the end of
    # the with statement, even if attempts to open files later
    # in the list raise an exception
```

Comment: Brilliant! That looks like exactly what I was looking for, but didn't know the name of for googling.